# How to list files from Share Point using Power Shell | system.net.webclient

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, webclient

I am able to download file from online share point using System.net.webclient, however not seeing any relevant method in System.net.webclient class (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8) to list the files in the folder. Below is the code snippet used to download file. Any help here to list out the files would be appreciated.

```
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $wc.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $SecurePassword)
    $wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    $wc.DownloadData($Source, $DownloadPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need get all files from the folder in SharePoint online library using CSOM with PowerShell, then using webclient to download all the files, the following example code for your reference.

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Setup Credentials to connect

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team"
$UserName="test@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password ="password"

#Folder's Site Relative Path 
$FolderURL= "Shared Documents/Subfolder"
$LocalPath="C:\temp\Subfolder"
#Get Credentials to connect
#$Cred = Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))  

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials 
#Get the Folder and Files
$Folder=$Ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderURL) 
$Ctx.Load($Folder) 
$Ctx.Load($Folder.Files) 
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
#Iterate through each File in the folder 

Try 
{
    Foreach($File in $Folder.Files) 
    {       
        $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
        $wc.Credentials =$Credentials
        $wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
        $FilePath=$SiteURL+"/"+$FolderURL+"/"+$File.Name        
        $DownloadPath=$LocalPath+"\"+$File.Name      
        $wc.DownloadFile($FilePath, $DownloadPath)
        $wc.Dispose()

    }
}
catch 
{
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```